# Convert UTF-8 String into CP860 in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have some strings in Python 3, they were supposed to be CP860 (Portuguese Language) but they are showing in UTF-8 I think. Can any one tell me how to convert that UTF-8 strings into CP860 strings in Python 3?

The string is " proteÃ§Ã£o para bebÃª " it should be as this  " de proteção para bebê "

I tried several codes but didn't work, sharing one of them here.

```
>>> a = "Cercadinho e grade de proteÃ§Ã£o para bebÃª".encode('cp860')

>>> print(a)

b'Cercadinho e grade de prote\x87\x84o para beb\x88' ==> Result
```

Result is wrong, it should be in CP860 ( de proteção para bebê ) as said above

Comment: What do you want? The result is correct, but you may write it to a file and read it with a CP860 reader (or a web browser with correct encoding information). If your console (locale/culture) is UTF-8, you will have such escapes.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to have is text that has been double-encoded, first as UTF-8, then latin-1.

```
>>> s = 'proteÃ§Ã£o para bebÃª'
>>> orig = s.encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')
>>> orig
'proteção para bebê'
```

You need to clean up the [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) first, then you can encode to cp860 if that's what you want to do:

```
>>> cp860 = orig.encode('cp860')
>>> cp860
b'prote\x87\x84o para beb\x88'
```

Note that in Python 3, encoded text is of type `bytes` rather than `str`, so it isn't really meaningful to say that you have or want "utf-8 strings" or "cp860 strings": there are bytestrings (`bytes`) which can be decoded to `str` from particular encoding (UTF-8, cp860 etc.).

Comment: http://prntscr.com/owb3vu  i am getting this error whenever i try to decode

Comment: i am following your simple code direct on my python3 command line console, but its not working for me and giving me UnicodeDecodeError i shared image link in my above comment.. i think something is wrong outside the code.. any idea?